# how to get first and last dates of past four months in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am trying to get the first and last dates of past four months. I have tried with following concept,

```
@staticmethod
def getDateRangeByMonth(year, month):
    """

    :param year:
    :param month:
    :return:
    """
    if year is None:
        today = datetime.today()
        year = today.year
    if month is None:
        today = datetime.today()
        month = today.month
    _, num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
    since = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.date(year, month, 
    1)), "%Y-%m-%d")
    till = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.date(year, month, 
    num_days)), "%Y-%m-%d")

    return since, till



 for i in range(0,4):
     today = datetime.today()
     since, till = getDateRangeByMonth(today.year, today.month - i)
```

I know the concept will fall when the past month crosses previous year like if the month is jan or feb then the year have to change.

How to alter this or what am i going wrong with this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified function, which gives you the desired number of previous months' start and end dates:

```
def getPrevDateRangeByMonth(year, month, prev):

    if year is None:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        year = today.year
    if month is None:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        month = today.month
    since = []
    till = []
    for i in range(prev):
        if month == 0:
            year -= 1
            month = 12
        _, num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
        since.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.date(year, month, 1)), "%Y-%m-%d"))
        till.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.date(year, month, num_days)), "%Y-%m-%d"))
        month -= 1
    return since, till

prev = 4
today = datetime.date.today()
since, till = getPrevDateRangeByMonth(2017, 3, prev)
for i in range(prev):
    print(since[i], till[i])
```

I have changed the `datetime.today()` to `datetime.date.today()` as that's how it works for me, you should probably change it back.

Comment: `if month <= 0:
            year = year - 1
            month = 12 - abs(month)`  I have used this

Comment: Not sure if you need all that, if you just keep track of the month value as you reduce it in every turn, and once it should move from Jan to Dec it will be reduced from 0 to -1. They you know you should be in December so you set it as 12, and reduce the year by one.

Answer (score 2):

In following code, the trick is that the datetime module offers `timedelta` to step one day sooner and `date.replace` to get first day of month. So here is a simple function:

```
def start_end_by_month(dat, delta):
    d = dat.replace(day = 1)
    till = []
    since = []
    for i in range(delta):
        d = d - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        till.append(d)
        d = d.replace(day=1)
        since.append(d)
    return since, till
```

Usage example:

```
>>> start_end_by_month(datetime.date(2008, 3, 10), 5)
([datetime.date(2008, 2, 1), datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), datetime.date(2007, 12, 1),
datetime.date(2007, 11, 1), datetime.date(2007, 10, 1)],
[datetime.date(2008, 2, 29), datetime.date(2008, 1, 31), datetime.date(2007, 12, 31),
datetime.date(2007, 11, 30), datetime.date(2007, 10, 31)])
```

showing that is easily skips a year boundary...

Comment: Very short and sweet answer @Serge